Trouble making an api call in wordpress site
I am new to making api calls on a wordpress theme site. Before implementing my api call into the wordpress site, I tested it on my local computer.
I used javascript for the frontend. And then I used php for the backend. Here's what i did:

I wrote the api call to make a call to my php backend
My php backend then made the api call to a 3rd party
The php backend then returns the information to the frontend
I render the information on the screen

Here is my javascript code:
const baseURL ='http://localhost/pledge-test-php/backend/functions.php';

function getOrgs(){
  return fetch(`${baseURL}?route=route1`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>{
      console.log(data)
      //return renderResults(data.results);

    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}

getOrgs();

And here is my functions.php code:
<?php
// Your PHP code here
//echo json_encode(["message" => "Hello from PHP!"]);
$url = 'https://api.pledge.to/v1/organizations';
$api_key = {my api key goes here};

// Set headers
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'header' => "Authorization: Bearer $api_key\r\n"
    ]
]);

if(isset($_GET['route'])) {
    $route = $_GET['route'];

    // Handle different routes
    if($route === 'route1') {
        // Code for route 1
        //echo json_encode(["message" => "Response from route 1"]);

        // Make HTTP GET request
        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    // Check if the request was successful
    if ($response === false) {
        // Handle error
        echo json_encode(["error" => "Failed to fetch data"]);
    } else {
        // Output the response as JSON
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        // Output the response
        echo $response;
    }
    }
}
?>


This all works on my computer. Now when I try to implement this into the wordpress site, it doesn't work. I think my problem is that my endpoint is wrong. Im not sure how to point to the functions.php file in the child theme of wordpress. Im suspecting this because I receive this error:
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON


In my javascript code I change the base URL to:
const baseURL = 'https://purgace.com/wp-content/themes/Divi%20Pledge%20Theme/functions.php'; 


In my child theme functions.php file, I implement my code like this:
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
 
    $parent_style = 'divi-style';
 
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );

//my code for api call below:

$url = 'https://api.pledge.to/v1/organizations';
$api_key = {my_api_key};

//set headers
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'header' => "Authorization: Bearer $api_key\r\n"
    ]
]);

if(isset($_GET['route'])) {
    $route = $_GET['route'];

    // Handle different routes
    if($route === 'route1') {
        // Code for route 1
        //echo json_encode(["message" => "Response from route 1"]);

        // Make HTTP GET request
        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    // Check if the request was successful
    if ($response === false) {
        // Handle error
        echo json_encode(["error" => "Failed to fetch data"]);
    } else {
        // Output the response as JSON
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        // Output the response
        echo $response;
    }
    }
}

?>

Does anyone know what the endpoint should be to call functions.php in my Wordpress child theme? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

This thread should belongs to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/. In any case, just define your const baseURL = 'https://purgace.com', functions.php will be included. You can't run PHP files directly if you configured your server to call only index.php file.

As it stands now... You have no hook to trigger your function.  So it would run a lot of times.  When do you want this to execute? Also you should look at using wp_remote_get https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/ for your API call instead of file_get_contents -

You should not be targeting your functions.php file directly to begin with. There is a proper way to "do AJAX in Wordpress", see https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

Your 'API' return the response as a json header('Content-Type: application/json');, then your javascript code is trying to parse that json and fails because the current response you are getting from the 3rd party is a HTML response not a json one.
